# Custom Slider in Infowindow not getting focus - Android Google Map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I am trying to create the setting panel at the info window such that we can use the slider inside the info window to adjust something. When it comes to the implementation and execution , I have found that the info window is always gaining the onclick focus. There are n NO any responses by clicking the sliders inside the info window. Woudl you please tell me how to make slider controls to be focused when the user clicks and drag the info windows 
?

The below is my code :

```
package com.larry.proto.maptest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Shader.TileMode;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  implements LocationListener {


    final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;

    private GoogleMap myMap;
    Location myLocation;
    LocationManager lm;
    private ArrayList<Checkpoint> cpList = new ArrayList<Checkpoint> ();
    private ArrayList<Marker> thisMarkerList = new ArrayList<Marker> ();
    private List<LatLng> ppoints = new ArrayList<LatLng> ();
    private int requestCode;
    private  LatLng globalPoint;
    private String infoDesp;
    private String infoLat;
    private String infoLong;
    private Marker mSelectedMarker;
    private boolean mRefreshingInfoWindow;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportMapFragment sFragment =  (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        myMap =  sFragment.getMap();
        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService (LOCATION_SERVICE);
        String provider = lm.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
        Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if(loc!=null)
        {
            onLocationChanged(loc);
        }
        SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
        String restoredLat = prefs.getString("lat", null);
        String restoredLng = prefs.getString("lng", null);
        String restoredText = prefs.getString("title", null);

        myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(setting());
        myMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);


        if(null!=restoredText){
            double lat = null!=restoredLat ? Double.parseDouble(restoredLat) : null;
            double lng = null!=  restoredLng ? Double.parseDouble(restoredLng) : null;
            LatLng posi = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(posi).title(restoredText) 
                    .snippet(String.valueOf(restoredLat) + "," + 
                            String.valueOf(restoredLng))
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(posi).zoom(14).build(); 
            myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
    }

    private OnMapLongClickListener setting() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new OnMapLongClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                globalPoint = point;
                requestCode = 0;
                Intent mIntent = new Intent();  
                mIntent.setClass(MainActivity.this,  SliderActivity.class);  
                startActivityForResult(mIntent, requestCode);  
            }};
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

        if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    RQS_GooglePlayServices);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LatLng latlng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude() , location.getLongitude());
        myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
        myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
    }


    private void addMarkersToMap() {
        myMap.clear();

        ppoints.clear();

        LatLng ll; 
        for (int i = 0; i < cpList.size(); i++) {         
            ll = new LatLng(cpList.get(i).getPoint().latitude, cpList.get(i).getPoint().longitude);
            ppoints.add(ll);
        }
        int length  = ppoints.size();
        LatLng first = null ;
        if(length >2){
            for( int i = 0 ; i < ppoints.size() -1  ; i++){
                first = ppoints.get(0);
                LatLng pt = ppoints.get(i);
                LatLng ptNext = ppoints.get(i+1);
                DrawArrowHead(myMap, pt, ptNext , Color.RED  , cpList.get(i).getDesp() , i+1 , true);
                createDashedLine(myMap, pt, ptNext , Color.RED);
            }
            List<LatLng> current =  ppoints.subList(ppoints.size()-2, ppoints.size());
            for( int i = 0 ; i < current.size() -1  ; i++){
                first = ppoints.get(0);
                LatLng pt = current.get(i);
                LatLng ptNext = current.get(i+1);
                DrawArrowHead(myMap, pt, ptNext , Color.BLUE , cpList.get(i).getDesp() ,i+1 , false);
                createDashedLine(myMap, pt, ptNext , Color.BLUE);
            }

            myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(first.latitude ,
                    first.longitude )).title("Starting Point") 
                    .snippet(String.valueOf(first.latitude) + "," + 
                            String.valueOf(first.longitude))
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
        }else if( length ==1){
            for( int i = 0 ; i < ppoints.size() ; i++){
                myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(ppoints.get(i).latitude ,
                        ppoints.get(i).longitude )).title("Starting Point") 
                        .snippet(String.valueOf(ppoints.get(i).latitude) + "," + 
                                String.valueOf(ppoints.get(i).longitude))
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
            }
        }

        else{



            myMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).addAll(ppoints));

            for( int i = 0 ; i < ppoints.size() -1  ; i++){
                first = ppoints.get(0);
                LatLng pt = ppoints.get(i);
                LatLng ptNext = ppoints.get(i+1);
                DrawArrowHead(myMap, pt, ptNext , Color.BLUE , cpList.get(i).getDesp() , i+1  , true);
                createDashedLine(myMap, pt, ptNext , Color.BLUE);
            }

            myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(first.latitude ,
                    first.longitude )).title("Starting Point") 
                    .snippet(String.valueOf(first.latitude) + "," + 
                            String.valueOf(first.longitude))
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
        }

    }

    private final double degreesPerRadian = 180.0 / Math.PI;


    private void DrawArrowHead(GoogleMap mMap, LatLng from, LatLng to , int color, String desp , int number , boolean boolR){
        double bearing = GetBearing(from, to);
        double adjBearing = Math.round(bearing / 3) * 3;
        while (adjBearing >= 120) {
            adjBearing -= 120;
        }
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
        URL url;
        Bitmap image = null;
        try {
            String name = "dir_" + String.valueOf((int)adjBearing) + ".png";
            String link = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/" + name;
            Log.d("ling k" , link);
            url = new URL(link);
            try {
                String imageName = link.substring(link.lastIndexOf("/"), link.length()); 
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +  imageName ); 
                if(!file.exists()){ 
                    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this , ImageIntentService.class).putExtra("urlpath", link));
                    Options  mBitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    mBitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444;
                    mBitmapOptions.inDither = true;
                    mBitmapOptions.inPurgeable = true;
                    mBitmapOptions.inInputShareable = true;
                    Rect rec = new Rect();
                    rec.set(-1, -1, -1, -1);
                    image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream() , rec  , mBitmapOptions);
                    image = getResizedBitmap(image ,  image.getHeight()*2 , image.getWidth()*2);
                }else{
                    Options  mBitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    mBitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444;
                    mBitmapOptions.inDither = true;
                    mBitmapOptions.inPurgeable = true;
                    mBitmapOptions.inInputShareable = true;
                    Rect rec = new Rect();
                    rec.set(-1, -1, -1, -1);
                    try {
                        image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, mBitmapOptions);
                        image = getResizedBitmap(image ,  image.getHeight()*2 , image.getWidth()*2);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (image != null){
            float anchorX = 0.5f;
            float anchorY = 0.5f;

            int offsetX = 0;
            int offsetY = 0;
            int width = image.getWidth();
            int height = image.getHeight();
            if (bearing >= 292.5 && bearing < 335.5){
                offsetX = 24;
                offsetY = 24;
                offsetX = width;
                offsetY = height;
            }
            else if (bearing >= 247.5 && bearing < 292.5){
                offsetX = 24;
                offsetY = 12;
                offsetX = width;
                offsetY = height/2;
            }
            else if (bearing >= 202.5 && bearing < 247.5){
                offsetX = 24;
                offsetY = 0;
                offsetX = width;
                offsetY = 0;
            }
            else if (bearing >= 157.5 && bearing < 202.5){
                offsetX = 12;
                offsetY = 0;
                offsetX = width/2;
                offsetY = 0;
            }
            else if (bearing >= 112.5 && bearing < 157.5){
                offsetX = 0;
                offsetY = 0;
            }
            else if (bearing >= 67.5 && bearing < 112.5){
                offsetX = 0;
                offsetY = 12;
                offsetX = 0;
                offsetY = height/2;
            }
            else if (bearing >= 22.5 && bearing < 67.5){
                offsetX = 0;
                offsetY = 24;
                offsetX = 0;
                offsetY = height;
            }
            else {
                offsetX = 12;
                offsetY = 24;
                offsetX = width/2;
                offsetY = height;
            }
            Bitmap wideBmp;
            Canvas wideBmpCanvas;
            Rect src, dest;

            wideBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth() *2, image.getHeight() * 2, image.getConfig());
            wideBmpCanvas = new Canvas(wideBmp); 

            src = new Rect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            dest = new Rect(src); 
            dest.offset(offsetX, offsetY); 
            Paint maskedPaint = new Paint();
            int r =  Color.red(color);
            int g =  Color.green(color);
            int b =  Color.blue(color);


            ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
            cm.set(new float[] {
                    1, 0, 0, 0, r,
                    0, 1, 0, 0, g,
                    0, 0, 1, 0, b,
                    0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }); // last line is antialias
            maskedPaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
            maskedPaint.setShader(new BitmapShader(image, TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT));

            // color
            wideBmpCanvas.drawBitmap(image, src, dest, maskedPaint);

            if(boolR == true){
                Paint stroke = new Paint();
                stroke.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                stroke.setAntiAlias(false);
                stroke.setStrokeWidth(8);
                stroke.setTextSize(60);
                wideBmpCanvas.drawText(String.valueOf(number), 
                        (float)wideBmpCanvas.getWidth()/2, (float)wideBmpCanvas.getHeight()/2, stroke);
            }
            infoDesp = desp;
            infoLat =String.valueOf(to.latitude);
            infoLong = String.valueOf(to.longitude);

             mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoAdapter());
             mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(to).title(desp)
            .snippet(String.valueOf(to.latitude) + "," + String.valueOf(to.longitude))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(wideBmp))
            .anchor(anchorX, anchorY));    
        }
    }

    class CustomInfoAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter{

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

            View marker = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).
                    inflate(R.layout.custom_marker_layout, null);

            if (!mRefreshingInfoWindow) {
                mSelectedMarker = arg0;

                TextView numTxt = (TextView) marker.findViewById(R.id.num_txt);
                TextView lat1 = (TextView) marker.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                TextView long1 = (TextView) marker.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                SeekBar sk  = (SeekBar) marker.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
                numTxt.setText(arg0.getTitle());
                lat1.setText(String.valueOf(arg0.getPosition().latitude));
                long1.setText(String.valueOf(arg0.getPosition().longitude));
                sk.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {       
                    @Override       
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }       
                    @Override       
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
                    }       
                    @Override       
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
                        if(progress==25){
                            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            v.vibrate(500);
                        }
                    }
                });
                sk.requestFocus();

            }else{
                refreshInfoWindow();
            }
            return marker;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        private void refreshInfoWindow() {
            if (mSelectedMarker == null) {
                return;
            }
            mRefreshingInfoWindow = true;
            mSelectedMarker.showInfoWindow();
            mRefreshingInfoWindow = false;
        }
    }


    private double GetBearing(LatLng from, LatLng to){
        double lat1 = from.latitude * Math.PI / 180.0;
        double lon1 = from.longitude * Math.PI / 180.0;
        double lat2 = to.latitude * Math.PI / 180.0;
        double lon2 = to.longitude * Math.PI / 180.0;

        double angle = - Math.atan2( Math.sin( lon1 - lon2 ) * Math.cos( lat2 ), 
                Math.cos( lat1 ) * Math.sin( lat2 ) - Math.sin( lat1 ) * Math.cos( lat2 ) * Math.cos( lon1 - lon2 ) );

        if (angle < 0.0)
            angle += Math.PI * 2.0;

        angle = angle * degreesPerRadian;

        return angle;
    }

    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }

    public void writeToFile(Checkpoint cp , String vertical , String circle ,  File f){
        OutputStreamWriter outStreamWriter = null;
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try {

            outStream = new FileOutputStream(f, true);
            outStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream); 
            outStreamWriter.write(new char[]{});
            outStreamWriter.append(cp.getDesp());
            outStreamWriter.append('\n');
            outStreamWriter.append(String.valueOf(cp.getPoint().latitude));
            outStreamWriter.append('\n');
            outStreamWriter.append(String.valueOf(cp.getPoint().longitude));
            outStreamWriter.append('\n');
            outStreamWriter.append("the vertical slider value is :" + vertical);
            outStreamWriter.append('\n');
            outStreamWriter.append("the circle slider value is :" + circle);
            outStreamWriter.append('\n');

            outStreamWriter.flush();
            outStreamWriter.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public static void createDashedLine(GoogleMap map, LatLng latLngOrig, LatLng latLngDest, int color){
        double difLat = latLngDest.latitude - latLngOrig.latitude;
        double difLng = latLngDest.longitude - latLngOrig.longitude;

        double zoom = map.getCameraPosition().zoom;

        double divLat = difLat / (zoom * 2);
        double divLng = difLng / (zoom * 2);

        LatLng tmpLatOri = latLngOrig;

        for(int i = 0; i < (zoom * 2); i++){
            LatLng loopLatLng = tmpLatOri;

            if(i > 0){
                loopLatLng = new LatLng(tmpLatOri.latitude + (divLat * 0.25f), tmpLatOri.longitude + (divLng * 0.25f));
            }

            Polyline polyline = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .add(loopLatLng).add(new LatLng(tmpLatOri.latitude + divLat, tmpLatOri.longitude + divLng))
            .color(color).width(5f));
            tmpLatOri = new LatLng(tmpLatOri.latitude + divLat, tmpLatOri.longitude + divLng);
        }
    }

    @Override  
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
        if(requestCode  ==0){
            if(resultCode ==RESULT_OK){
                String change01 = data.getStringExtra("change01");  
                String change02 = data.getStringExtra("change02");  

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this  , change01 + " " + change02 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Checkpoint cp = new Checkpoint("Destination", globalPoint, 0);
                Log.d("lati long" , String.valueOf(globalPoint.latitude) + ":" +  String.valueOf(globalPoint.longitude));
                cpList.add(cp);

                File dir = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
                        File.separator + "NOVAX" );
                if(!dir.exists()){
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }


                Checkpoint lastlyAdded = cpList.get(cpList.size() -1 );
                writeToFile(lastlyAdded ,  change01 , change02 ,    new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator +  "text.txt" ));

                SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.clear();
                editor.putString("title", lastlyAdded.getDesp());
                editor.putString("lat", String.valueOf(lastlyAdded.getPoint().latitude));
                editor.putString("lng",  String.valueOf(lastlyAdded.getPoint().longitude));
                editor.commit();

                for(int i = 0 ; i < cpList.size() ; i ++){
                    Checkpoint cPoint =  cpList.get(i);
                    if(!cPoint.getPoint().equals(lastlyAdded.getPoint())){
                        cPoint.setState(1); 
                        cPoint.setDesp("Checkpoint "+String.valueOf(i+1) );
                    }
                }
                addMarkersToMap();
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Google's documentation, custom info windows are not real windows, but instead a rendered image inserted into the map view. The only items in a google map that can gain focus seem to be the markers themselves. The info windows an take a onClickListener though. Here's the relevant info. Look at the note in the [Custom Info Windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows#custom_info_windows) section in their docs.

> Note: The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is rendered as an image (using View.draw(Canvas)) at the time it is returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window later (for example, after an image has loaded), call showInfoWindow(). Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as described in the section below.

There may be a way to use a FrameLayout and a view overtop, acting like a custom info window, but that's more of a hack than a supported solution.